# How to override default class of custom text field in views?

Tags: 7, views, theming

How can I change the *nothing* in the "views-field-nothing" class of a custom text field in views?

I just can't find the appropriate setting...

Comment: use views-field tpl file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found it myself. Sometimes you have to ask to look into something unexpected...

In style settings it's the "Customize field and label wrapper HTML" -settings i was looking for. With "create a css-class" you can override the default setting of the wrapper.

[image]

Thanks for looking anyway...